# How to fill a NULL column field with the last non null value in the same column in Teradata?

Tags: teradata

My table looks like this which I am trying to fix:

```
calendar_date   BNK_CUST_NBR    SNPSHT_DT   blnce_daywise
11/2/2018       XYZ             11/2/2018   0
11/3/2018       ?               ?           ?
11/4/2018       ?               ?           ?
11/5/2018       XYZ             11/5/2018   0
11/6/2018       XYZ             11/6/2018   0
11/7/2018       XYZ             11/7/2018   10
11/8/2018       XYZ             11/8/2018   10
11/9/2018       XYZ             11/9/2018   35
11/10/2018      ?               ?           ?
11/11/2018      ?               ?           ?
11/12/2018      ?               ?           ?
11/13/2018      XYZ             11/13/2018  35
11/14/2018      XYZ             11/14/2018  35
11/15/2018      XYZ             11/15/2018  35
11/16/2018      XYZ             11/16/2018  35
```

I basically want to use blnce_daywise and fill its null values with the last non null value: Like 0 against dates `11/3/2018` and `11/4/2018` and 35 in `11/10/2018`, `11/11/2018` and `11/12/2018`

I used following code but its basically not working.

`Last_Value(BLNCE_DAYWISE ignore NULLS) Over (PARTITION BY BNK_CUST_NBR  ORDER BY CALENDAR_DATE  ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS BLNCE_DAYWISE_30_DAYS`

Comment: Your `BNK_CUST_NBR` has NULLs, you need to remove it from PARTITION. How do you create the current result set? And what's your Teradata release?

Comment: Teradata 15.10.1.8
You are right about BNK_CUST_NBR. I realized it late. But how to fill BNK_CUST_NBR first for every date, before executing Last_Value for balance?

Comment: It should work if you remove the PARTITION